# Renaming multiple files in the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have multiple files with names

```
x_beta_5.txt
x_beta_20.txt
x_beta_300.txt
and the list goes one
```

how can the name of these files can be changed to

```
x_5.txt
x_20.txt
x_300.txt
```

I have tried using the ren command in the following manner (which works on single files)

```
ren x_beta_*.txt x_*.txt
```

but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for the
[ren command](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
make this a very difficult case.

It's much easier using PowerShell, for the current folder :

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem x_beta_*.txt  | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'beta_','' }"
```

The command `powershell` is required in a CMD session.
It's not required if you start a PowerShell session.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: @jarhead , would you mind elaborating?  what happened?

Comment: It worked for me - have you copy-pasted the command ?

Comment: it is fine. my mistake